# How to pipe manpage to grep?

Tags: grep

So I want to quickly find the meaning of "^" in a grep code and this is my code:

```
 man grep|grep "^"
```

But unfortunately the output is not what I desired.
It seems that it simply reprint everything in the grep manual which makes it impossible for me to quickly find the information I wanted.
[image]

Comment: Change `PAGER` to `less`

Comment: You can search in man page (without grepping): https://askubuntu.com/questions/20752/how-can-i-search-within-a-manpage

Comment: Please post text as text. Images of text have accessibility problems: i.e. hard to read, and near impossible to read by blind people.

Comment: The irony is, that after reading that part of the man page your would know why grep is not interpreting `^` as a literal `^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep(1)` manual describes the `grep` utility, but since this is only one of several utilities using regular expressions on a Unix system, the regular expressions themselves have a separate manual, `re_format(7)`. This is mentioned in the section of the `grep(1)` manual that you show in the question.

Since `^` is has a special meaning at the start of any regular expression (it matches the empty space at the start of any line), you can't use `^` as is in a regular expression to look for it.  As you have already noticed, the regular expression `^` matches on *every line*.  Instead, you have to  escape it as `\^`.

```
man re_format | grep '\^'
```

You can also ask `grep` to treat the given pattern as a *string* rather than as a regular expression using its `-F` option:

```
man re_format | grep -F '^'
```

If you're using a `grep` that has an `-A` option, then you may use this options to give you a certain number of lines of trailing context, as in e.g.

```
man re_format | grep -A 5 -F '^'
```

What I would suggest you do is to set the environment variable `PAGER` or `MANPAGER` to `less` (not necessary on macOS as `less` is the default pager), type `man re_format`, and then use <kbd>/</kbd> in `less` to search for the bits of the manual that you want to read.  The search functionality in `less` takes a regular expression search pattern, so you would have to search for `\^` to look for the `^` character itself.

Or, press <kbd>/</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to search for strings that won't be interpreted as regular expressions (similarly as with `grep -F`, although `*` and `!` are special if either of them are the first character of the search string; see the `less(1)` manual). When using  <kbd>/</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to search in `less`, the ordinary search prompt (`/`) changes to `Regex-off /`.